# What is a better way of converting a HashMap to HTML in Rust?

Tags: html, rust, serde

I am trying to convert a HashMap to HTML with Rust. The conversion to JSON is a much simpler subject.

I came up with this:

```rust
fn convert_headers_to_html(headers: HashMap<String, Vec<String>>) -> String {
    let mut html_table_header = String::new();
    let mut html_table_content = String::new();

    html_table_header.push_str("<table>");
    html_table_header.push_str("<tr>");
    html_table_content.push_str("<tr>");
    for (k, v) in headers {
        //
        html_table_header.push_str("<th>");
        html_table_header.push_str(&k);
        html_table_header.push_str("</th>");

        html_table_content.push_str("<td>");
        html_table_content.push_str(&v.join(" "));
        html_table_content.push_str("</td>");
    }
    html_table_header.push_str("</tr>");
    html_table_content.push_str("</tr>");
    html_table_content.push_str("</table>");

    html_table_header.push_str(&html_table_content);
    html_table_header
}
```

It just feels overly verbose.

Is there a better way?

Comment: This is just one possible way to format a hashmap like that, so no, I don't think there's a shorter generic function.

Comment: unless you decide to use some form of templating and you can use the string `format!` macro to make more one liners

Comment: Note that the order of hashmap is not defined, so it may not result in what you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use a template:

```rust
<table>
    <tr>
        {% for header in headers %}
        <th> {{ header }} </th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    <tr>
        {% for datum in data %}
        <td>{{ datum }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>
```

And then using the template:

```rust
use askama::Template;

#[derive(Template)]
#[template(path = "echo.html")]
struct EchoTemplate {
    headers: Vec<String>,
    data: Vec<String>,
}



fn convert_headers_to_html(headers: HashMap<String, Vec<String>>) -> String {
    let html_table = EchoTemplate {
        headers: headers.keys().cloned().collect(),
        data: headers.values().cloned().map(|v| v.join(" ")).collect(),
    };

    match html_table.render() {
        Ok(html) => html,
        _ => "Could not convert headers to html table".to_string(),
    }
}
```

Works very well.